# Facebook sharing hide the message in phonegap plugin

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, mobile, facebook-social-plugins

I used this plugin for sharing any text on my Android mobile App
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share

and every thing is ok, expect one thing

when I write some text and I want to share it, the plugin opens a list of sharing programs, and I can select any one and share the text that I wrote before, but if I select facebook sharing, it delete the text I wrote, and show to user an empty text area, and ignore the text that I called the plugin with

Any Suggestions???

Thanks,
Mohammed Elrashidy

Comment: Please post your JS code.

Comment: As I wrote, I included the plugin in the link that I posted,
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share
and I wrote this function in my index file

    window.plugins.share.show({
        subject: 'hello',
        text: 'share this link http://www.mndaily.com'},
        function() {}, // Success function
        function() {alert('Share failed')} // Failure function
    );

if I select facebook sharing, it will has the link in the text attribute only in its sharing area and will not has the sting "share this link"

Answer (score 0):

Hate to answer with another answer, but it looks like you can't share text and a link.  Either or, according to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505365/227313

Answer (score 0):

After release phonegap 3.0 they have remove all plugin from phonegap(github) So you have to upgrade it to latest version.

you can find sharing plugin at its easy to use and install [here](http://www.excellentwebworld.com/simple-way-to-integrate-sharethis-plugin-with-phonegap-3-0/)