# share image does not work in viber and facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, viber

I use the code below for sharing images but unfortunately it works only for **Line**, not for **Facebook** and **Viber**

**Code:**

```
 Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 share.setType("image/png");
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(G.DIR_APP + "/sample_image.png"));
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image"));
```

Comment: and how is that suppose to work for `facebook`

Comment: can you let me know what is complete path here of the bitmap ?

Comment: facebook app open but image doesn't display

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505279/sharing-content-on-facebook-android)?

Comment: Anyway, some guy pointed this out
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent):
"Facebook IGNORES our text. They say "These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice." One workaround is to use the Facebook SDK to post, but that doesn't allow the user to choose how they want to share. We can also make a custom landing page, and the link will show the <meta content ="..."> text from that page with our link in Facebook."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share directly to Facebook and Viber...

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/png");
share.setPackage("com.facebook.katana"); 
//for viber package is "com.viber.voip".
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ImageUri);
startActivity(p_intent.createChooser(share, "Share With"));
```